# VBA - Error handling with writing the arguments

Tags: vba, excel, custom-error-handling

Hello nice friendly people. I would be as specific as possible. The question is the following:

Why the first line works in the VBE immediate window, while the second one does not?
How can I make the second line work?

```
err.Raise 999,,"EA"
err.Raise err.Number:= 999,err.Description:= "EA"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't refer to `err.X` in your call, just set `X:=...`:

```
err.Raise Number:=999, Description:= "EA"
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`err` is the actual error object, and for the `.Raise` method you are supplying arguments. This error has nothing to do with it being in the immediate window - it won't work in a module either because the syntax is wrong.

If you are supplying all the arguments in the order that they are expected - then there is no need to specify the argument's header information:

e.g. The [`Workbook.SaveAs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff841185.aspx) method

> ***.SaveAs**(**FileName, FileFormat, Password, WriteResPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended, CreateBackup, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout, Local**)*

You could write:

```
wb.SaveAs "myFile.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook, "Password123", "Passsword123", True,,,,,,,,
```

But if you wanted to skip some out in between and not have commas all over the place (which makes for much better readability) you could do something like this:

```
wb.SaveAs FileName:="myFile.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
```

---

Carrying on this example, what you have done is re-reference the object and tried to access a property that doesn't yet exist:

```
wb.SaveAs wb.FileName:="myFile.xlsx", wb.FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

If you're accessing a property of an object, you are either *reading* or *writing* to/from that property.

- `myVariable = wb.Name` (Read)
- `wb.Name = myVariable` (Write)

Both of these operations use the `=` operator.

Where you have written `err.Number:=999` the compiler is expecting a read/write operation using the `=` operator which is why an error is caused.

Hopefully that explains it in a little more detail.

Comment: Yup, it does. I did not think of the re-referencing part.